# How can I play a gif when scrolled into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here a code that have 2 events for gifs:

1. "play gif when you click it"
2. "play gif when you hover cursor over gif".

I want to change first event  "play gif when you click it" into "play a gif when scrolled into view", It's that possible ? Thanks.

```
/*
 * Based on:
 * Gifplayer v0.1.0
 * (c)2014 Rubén Torres - rubentdlh@gmail.com
 * Released under the MIT license
 */

(function($) {

    function GapPlayer(preview, options) {
        this.previewElement = preview;
        this.spinnerElement = $("<div class='spinner'></div>");
        this.options = options;
        this.gifLoaded = false;
    }

    GapPlayer.prototype = {

        activate: function() {
            this.wrap();
            this.addSpinner();
            this.addControl();
            this.addEvents();
            if (this.options.autoLoad) {
                this.playElement.hide();
                this.spinnerElement.show();
                this.loadGif();
            }
            if (this.options.preLoad) {
                (new Image()).src = this.getGifSrc();
            }
        },

        wrap: function(){
            this.wrapper = this.previewElement.wrap("<div class='gapplayer-wrapper'></div>").parent();
            this.wrapper.css('width', this.previewElement.width());
            this.wrapper.css('height', this.previewElement.height());
            this.previewElement.addClass('gapplayer');
            this.previewElement.css('cursor','pointer');
        },

        getGifSrc: function(){
            var gifSrc;
            if (this.previewElement.attr('data-gif')) {
                gifSrc = this.previewElement.attr('data-gif');
            } else {
                gifSrc = this.previewElement.attr('src').replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ".gif");
            }
            return gifSrc;
        },

        addControl: function(){
            this.playElement = $("<ins class='play-gif'>" + this.options.label + "</ins>");
            this.playElement.css('left', this.previewElement.width()/2 + this.playElement.width()/2);
            this.wrapper.append(this.playElement);
        },

        addEvents: function() {
            var onEvent = this.options.hover ? 'mouseenter' : 'click',
                gp = this;
            gp.playElement.on(onEvent, function(e) {
                $(this).hide();
                gp.spinnerElement.show();
                gp.loadGif();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            gp.previewElement.on(onEvent, function(e) {
                if (gp.playElement.is(':visible')) {
                    gp.playElement.hide();
                    gp.spinnerElement.show();
                    gp.loadGif();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            gp.spinnerElement.on(onEvent, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        },

        loadGif: function() {
            if (! this.gifLoaded) {
                this.enableAbort();
            }
            var gp = this,
                onEvent = gp.options.hover ? 'mouseleave' : 'click',
                gifSrc = this.getGifSrc(),
                gifWidth = this.previewElement.width(),
                gifHeight = this.previewElement.height();

            gp.gifElement = $("<img src='" + gifSrc + "' width='" + gifWidth + "' height=' "+ gifHeight + " '/>");
            this.gifElement.load(function() {
                gp.gifLoaded = true;
                gp.resetEvents();
                $(this).css({'position': 'absolute',
                            'top': '0',
                            'left': '0'});

                // Start animation
                if (gp.options.effect) {
                    gp.gifElement.hide();
                    gp.spinnerElement.hide();
                    gp.wrapper.append(gp.gifElement);
                    gp.gifElement.stop(true).fadeIn(function() {
                        gp.previewElement.hide();
                    });
                } else {
                    gp.previewElement.hide();
                    gp.wrapper.append(gp.gifElement);
                    gp.spinnerElement.hide();
                }

                if (! gp.options.autoLoad) {
                    $(this).on(onEvent, function(e) {

                        // Stop animation
                        if (gp.options.effect) {
                            gp.previewElement.show();
                            gp.playElement.show();
                            $(this).stop(true).fadeOut();
                        } else {
                            $(this).remove();
                            gp.previewElement.show();
                            gp.playElement.show();
                        }

                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    });
                }
            });
        },

        enableAbort: function() {
            var gp = this;
            this.previewElement.click(function(e) {
                gp.abortLoading(e);
            });
            this.spinnerElement.click(function(e) {
                gp.abortLoading(e);
            });
        },

        abortLoading: function(e) {
            this.spinnerElement.hide();
            this.playElement.show();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.gifElement.off('load').on('load', function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                ev.stopPropagation();
            });
            this.resetEvents();
        },

        resetEvents: function() {
            this.previewElement.off('click');
            this.playElement.off('click');
            this.spinnerElement.off('click');
            this.addEvents();
        },

        addSpinner: function() {
            this.wrapper.append(this.spinnerElement);
            this.spinnerElement.hide();
        }

    };

    $.fn.gapPlayer = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            options = $.extend({}, $.fn.gapPlayer.defaults, options);
            var gapPlayer = new GapPlayer($(this), options);
            gapPlayer.activate();
        });
    };

    $.fn.gapPlayer.defaults = {
        label: 'gif',
        autoLoad: false,
        preLoad: false,
        effect: false,
        hover: false
    };

    // Start plugin
    gapStart();

})(jQuery);

function gapStart() {
    if (gapParams.metadata == 'yes')
        jQuery('img[src$="-gap.jpg"]:not([data-gif]):not(.gapplayer),img[src*="-gap.jpg?"]:not([data-gif]):not(.gapplayer)').each(function() {
            var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            jQuery(this).attr('data-gif', src.substring(0, src.length - 8) + '.gif');
        });

    var gifs = jQuery('img[src$="-gap.jpg"]:not(.gapplayer),img[src*="-gap.jpg?"]:not(.gapplayer)');
    gifs.imagesLoaded(function() {
        gifs.gapPlayer({
            autoLoad: gapParams.autoLoad == 'yes',
            preLoad: gapParams.preLoad == 'no',
            effect: gapParams.effect == 'yes',
            hover: gapParams.hover == 'yes'
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two things 
1: Is that GIF `placeholder image` 
2: That `GIF source`

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/v46q7wtv/

This stuff are good to making the sticky nav bar too,you just need to add a class and remove class

Comment: Em sorry mate,i'm not an JS pro,and i try my best to soft it,but if i got something i can help you,i'll contact you agagin

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping me but I don't really understand what I need to do and I want also if user scroll down or up from that post/gif , gif to be stopped automatically

Comment: Hello Alex,i update the code,and this time if the image in on user screen it will become a GIF,but if is off the screen it will back to a placeholder image again,and this time i'm using a jQuery plugin call visible

Comment: Hey Felix, the only problem it's I don't know how to integrate your script into my script .. 0% knowledge javascript... but I will try..

Comment: on my script I have 2 events : first , placeholder it's thumbnail from gif and if you click it gif it's play it and second , placeholder it's thumbnail from gif and if you hover with mouse over gif will play it, but I don't know how to some of this events.

Comment: Is easy to listen this two event mate,and i help you to update the code,if you got and problem with that,feel free to ask,and i'll try help to you,and by the way are you new to jQuery and JS like me?

Comment: yes..seems so hard to learn this languages...I'm still trying with that code :)

Comment: Oh,jQuery is the most easy language i see,and did i soft problem,and if you got any more,we can chat using http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes,I would like if you have time to help me to modify that code with your script.